# Can't use Amazon S3 API over SSL?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use Amazon S3 API to encrypt and upload a file.

```
public class AmazonS3 {

    String KmsId = "my_id_comes_here";

    private TransferManager getTransferManager() {
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
        KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider materialProvider = new KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider(KmsId);
        AmazonS3EncryptionClient s3Client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(awsCredentials, materialProvider,
                new CryptoConfiguration().withKmsRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1)).withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1);
        s3Client.setEndpoint("s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com");
        TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(s3Client);
        return transferManager;
    }

    public void upload(String bucket, String keyName, String filePath)
            throws InterruptedException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        TransferManager transferManager = getTransferManager();
        // TransferManager processes all transfers asynchronously, so this call will return immediately.
        Upload upload = transferManager.upload(bucket, keyName, new File(filePath));

        try {
            // Or you can block and wait for the upload to finish
            upload.waitForCompletion();
            System.out.println("Upload complete.");
        } catch (AmazonClientException amazonClientException) {
            System.out.println("Unable to upload file, upload was aborted.");
            amazonClientException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Which works fine if **I don't pass my** **trustore** as arguments to my application.

But, if **I initialize my application with my trustore** like this:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="dev" -Djavax.net.debug=all -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/share/ca-certificates/anevis/java/activemq/client.ts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

It gives me this error:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:516)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:317)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3595)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:999)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager.doDownload(TransferManager.java:779)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager.download(TransferManager.java:691)
    at com.anevis.documentengine.configuration.jms.AmazonS3.download(AmazonS3.java:57)
    at com.anevis.documentengine.configuration.jms.S3UploadTest.testUpload(S3UploadTest.java:25)
    at com.anevis.documentengine.configuration.jms.S3UploadTest.main(S3UploadTest.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:535)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:749)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:505)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 38 more
```

How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your trust store doesn't have the certificate authority that secures the AWS APIs.  You need to create a new trust store that combines `client.ts` with the ones required for AWS.  The easiest way to do this is to merge `client.ts` with the `cacerts` keystore from the JRE.

Example:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.ts -destkeystore combined.ts -srcstorepass changeit -deststorepass changeit
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -destkeystore combined.ts -srcstorepass changeit -deststorepass changeit
```

Then use `combined.ts` instead of `client.ts`.

Comment: You are just a savior! Awesome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a similar issue: when I have no ssl store, everything works fine, but when I try to access S3 through my server with has AWS RDS root certs attached, I get the same exception. What type of certificate do I have to ask AWS for? And do I attach it to the same truststore that has the RDS root cert?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, we had similar problem but I tweaked response a little bit for our scenario.

I received this com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

exception when trying to connect to AmazonDynamoDB.

When we moved our application to HTTPS we started receiving this error.

So the solution was the same, the only difference was instead of client.ts I had to add certificate into cacerts which was generated during HTTPS migration.

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -destkeystore test.p12 -srcstorepass changeit -deststorepass test;

Thanks,