# SunCertPathBuilderException while trying to connect to Amazon S3 through Groovy and intellij

Tags: java, ssl, intellij-idea, amazon-s3, groovy

I have this code where I am using `Groovy(2.4)` and intellij to connect `Amazon S3` and get the list of buckets in S3:

```
import org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service
import org.jets3t.service.model.S3Bucket
import org.jets3t.service.model.S3Object
import org.jets3t.service.security.AWSCredentials


class s3_read {   

    static void main(def args){

        String awsAccessKey = "accessKey";
        String awsSecretKey = "secretAccesKey";
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials =
                new AWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

        RestS3Service s3Service = new RestS3Service(awsCredentials);

        S3Bucket[] myBuckets = s3Service.listAllBuckets();
        println("How many buckets to I have in S3? " + myBuckets.length);

    }

}
```

When I execute this code I get error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: Request Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.jets3t.service.S3Service.listAllBuckets(S3Service.java:1461)
    at org.jets3t.service.S3Service$listAllBuckets.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)

    at s3_read.main(s3_read.groovy:28)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1969)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:318)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:312)
    at 
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:290)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:343)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:226)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.checkServerCerts(ClientHandshaker.java:1825)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 39 more
```

I looked around for similar error examples but couldn't find one related to using it with Amazon S3. What could be the reason for this error and the way to correct it?

Comment: This one may help: [Can't use Amazon S3 API over SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158714/cant-use-amazon-s3-api-over-ssl)

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez where is client.ts present and is syntax mentioned in the answer on the link for Windows 8?