# Unable to access S3 from Tomcat due to SSLHandshakeException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tomcat7, aws-sdk

I am trying to create a s3 bucket and the code looks like below

```
public void createS3Bucket(String bucketName){
    LOG.debug("creating S3 Bucket with name {}",bucketName);
    Bucket bucket = null;
    try {
        if (!doesBucketExists(bucketName)) {
            bucket = s3Client.createBucket(bucketName);

            setServerSideEncryption(bucketName);

            setBucketLoggingAccess(bucketName);
        }else {
            throw new Exception("bucket already exists");
        }
    }catch (SdkClientException e) {
        catch block
    }
}
```

This is called as part of a rest service and the service is deployed in tomcat. When I call the service, it fails to create s3 bucket by throwing below exception

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1116)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1066)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4325)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4272)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getAcl(AmazonS3Client.java:3477)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketAcl(AmazonS3Client.java:1171)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketAcl(AmazonS3Client.java:1161)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExistV2(AmazonS3Client.java:1296)
... 43 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy68.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1238)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1058)
... 57 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
... 84 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
... 90 more
```

When I execute the same as stand alone app, then the same code is working fine.

We are using a trust store and I have tried to include the AWS certificates in the trust store and i am still facing the same issue

**EDIT1**

```
java version: "1.8.0_151"
Tomcat version: "8.0.53"
```

I am using a custom trust store. But I have exported the aws certificate from browser and merged it with my custom trust store using keytool. Still there is no use.

Answer (score 0):

You did not include the java version used by Tomcat or when you test the code locally.  It will be helpful to list both `java -version` output.

You also did not specify if you are using the system trust store or if you are using a custom one.  It would be useful to give the full `java` command used to launch tomcat and to launch your local test.

The error means that the local Java runtime can not find the root certificates required to establish the TLS connection.  It might be a very old version of java ?  It might be a custom trust store that you created yourself and that does not include the AWS root certificates ?

Modern operating systems and Java versions after than 1.4.2_12 should include the Amazon root certificates.  But, again, we do not know from your question which version is used and which trust store is used.

This article will give you more details : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prepare-for-aws-move-to-its-own-certificate-authority/

This question is similar and has probably good hints too : [Can't use Amazon S3 API over SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158714/cant-use-amazon-s3-api-over-ssl)